# Characterizing a modular form via its first Fourier coefficients at infinity

Tags: modular-forms

It is well known that a cusp form 
$$
f = \sum_{n\ge 1}a_n q^n
$$ 
of weight $k$ and level $1$ is determined by its first $d_k = \text{dim } S_k$ coefficients. This follows from the valence formula (which gives a bound) and from an explicit construction using Eisenstein series.

What happens in higher levels, for instance for the group $\Gamma_0(N)$? The valence formula still gives a bound, but can we pinpoint the smallest integer $d_{k,N}$ such that $f \in S_{k}(\Gamma_0(N))$ vanishes if and only if $a_n=0$ for $1\le n \le d_{k,N}$?

What is known and what is conjectured?

Answer (score 3):

In his paper [Congruences between Modular Forms](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a15d/2158f5805059a1553582ac83d46d772e270f.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwib8bPTk6HjAhWjiOAKHQ74BtIQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3Gv4iEM1a33Qy7JbVTRZmS), Ram Murty proves a number of results in the spirit of your question. For example, his Theorem 1 is:

**Theorem**: *Let f and g be distinct holomorphic modular forms of weight $k$ and levels $N_1$ and $N_2$. Let $N=\mathrm{Lcm}(N_1,N_2)$. Then for some $$ n \leq \frac{k}{12}N\prod_{p\mid N}\left( 1+\frac{1}{p}\right)$$ we must have $a_f(n)\neq a_g(n)$.*

**Added**: As Kimball has pointed out in a comment, Theorem 4 of this paper is not correct. For more details you should take a look at the paper [Distinguishing Hecke Eigenforms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4705) by Alexandru Ghitza.

Comment: Though perhaps one should caution the reader that not all of the results in that paper are correct.  See Alex Ghitza's "Distinguishing Hecke eigenforms" paper for a corrected version of Murty's Theorem 4.

Comment: @Kimball - Thanks for pointing that out! I actually wasn't aware that some of the results in the paper weren't correct. I'll edit the post to include a link to Ghitza's paper.

Comment: Sure, I'm not aware of any issues with the other theorems, but I also haven't read that paper.

Comment: The above theorem was first proved by Jacob Sturm, "On the congruence of modular forms" (1984).  His version has the weaker requirement that $a_f(n)\neq a_g(n)\pmod{M}$ (with a corresponding generalization when the coefficients lie in a number field other than $\mathbb{Q}$).  There is some additional discussion of this in Ken Ono's book "The Web of Modularity" in section 2.9.